# Do all logic problems have one solution?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Analyze the logical forms of the following statements:

x and y are natural numbers, and exactly one of them is prime.

Below are the two answers that I got. The first one is the one the author provides to me in his book. The second one is the answer that I got.

N(x) ∧ N(y) ∧ [(P(x)∧¬P(y)) ∨ (P(y)∧¬P(x))], where N(x)

**means “x is a natural number” and P(x) means “x is prime.”**

N(x) ^ N(y) ^ (P(x) v P(y)),

**where N(x) and N(y) means x are  natural numbers and P(x) or P(y) means x or y are a prime number.**

The issue that I have is that in his answer he states that x is a natural number and p(x)  is a prime number but in no way does he ever mention anything about p(y) like I do.

Notice the bold statements in each.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused (who is the 'he' in 'he states', for example), but the two logical propositions you've written are distinct.  When $N(x),N(y),P(x),P(y)$ are all true the second is true, but the first is false.  More generally, two logical propositions may be logically equivalent, but this may be extremely inobvious.  A lot of works goes into designing circuits via computers, and the algorithms they use to try to 'rewrite' the circuit in a more efficient but equivalent form.

Comment: N(x) & N(y) & [P(x) ^ P(y)] -> (x is natural and y is natural and (x is prime xor y is prime). I do not understand your question but it can be helpful to you

Comment: I don't understand what your issues are. Could you maybe consider rephrasing your question(s)?

Comment: The NAND operator also includes the case that neither of the operands is true. I think you're confusing it with XOR. But for the first issue, if you know what the problem is with your answer, and you know how to fix the problem, what's the question? And for the second issue, what do you mean? I can see two instances of $P(y)$ in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your answer and what "he" says is that he claims exactly one is prime and in yours both can be primes.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about the confusion but you understood it correctly.Youre awesome

Comment: There you go. Thanks again

Comment: You gave it to the wrong guy...

Answer (score 1):

> I have two issues with my problem. The first one is that if I wanted to indicate $p(x)$ or $p(y)$ but not both, then I would use the nand operator $\uparrow$. Right now what my answer is saying is the following: $p(x)$ or $p(y)$ or both are prime.

Yes.   You need to exclude the case where both are prime.   That requires an xor connective,  $\oplus\;$.

$$\begin{align}
P(x)\oplus P(y) \;& \equiv\; \big(P(x)\vee P(y)\big)\wedge \big(P(x)\uparrow P(y)\big)
\\[1ex]
 & \equiv\; \big(P(x)\vee P(y)\big)\wedge\neg\big(P(x)\wedge P(y)\big)
\\[1ex]
 & \equiv\; \big(P(x)\wedge \neg P(y)\big)\vee \big(\neg P(x)\wedge P(y)\big)
\end{align}$$

> The second issue that I have is that in his answer he states that $N(x)$ is a natural number and $P(x)$ is a prime number but in no way does he ever mention anything about $P(y)$ like I do.

It's not required.   Once $P(x)$ is defined to mean "$x$ is prime", then defining $P(y)$ to mean "$y$ is prime" is redundant.   What else would it mean?

The $x$ in the definition of predicate $P$ is a 'dummy variable', and can be alpha-replaced with any entity.   Once $P$ is so defined then $P(z)$ *must not* mean anything other than "$z$ is prime".

Comment: Youre awesome. Thank you so much .